# Future.isDone() does not show state change when using executor.scheduleAtFixedRate method

Tags: java, concurrency

Hi I'm a newbie to concurrency so I wrote a very basic program to see whether on a threads completion the future.isDone() method shows true, unfortunately it always shows "false" when I schedule the task with scheduledAtFixedRate method. However  if I use schedule method it shows "true" of course the simple task does not rerun seconds later. Any suggestions or explanations to help me understand why this is the case would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Here with the code:

```
package com.company;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Main mn = new Main();
    System.out.println("Main thread started...");
    mn.runobjects();
    System.out.println("Main thread stopping...");
}



@Test
public void runobjects(){
    List<commonrun> Obj = new ArrayList<>();
    Obj.add(new TestObj1());
    Obj.add(new TestObj2());
    Obj.add(new TestObj3());
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
    ScheduledFuture<?> futures1 = null;
    ScheduledFuture<?> futures2 = null;
    ScheduledFuture<?> futures3 = null;
    int i=0;
    for (commonrun  obj : Obj){
        if (i==0) {
            futures1 = executor.schedule(() -> obj.runme(), 0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        if (i==1) {
            futures2 = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> obj.runme(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        if (i==2) {
            futures3 = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> obj.runme(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        i++;
    }

    while(true){

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread 1 is done   : "+ futures1.isDone());
        System.out.println("Thread 2 is done   : "+ futures2.isDone());
        System.out.println("Thread 3 is done   : "+ futures3.isDone());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
}

package com.company;

public interface commonrun {

    public void runme();
}

package com.company;

public class TestObj1 implements commonrun {

    static int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void runme() {
        System.out.println("Object 1 Starting... run : " + counter);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Object 1 Stopping... run : " + counter);
        counter++;

    }
}

package com.company;

public class TestObj2 implements commonrun {
    @Override
    public void runme() {
        System.out.println("Object 2 Starting...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         System.out.println("Object 2 Stopping...");

    }
}

package com.company;

public class TestObj3 implements commonrun {
    @Override
    public void runme() {
        System.out.println("Object 3 Starting...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Object 3 Stopping...");

    }
}
```

Comment: This is because using "executor.scheduleAtFixedRate()" does not return any Future-Objects. This decision was made because the method would return a new Future-Object every time the task gets executed. And as nobody knows how often this task gets executed, the designers of Java decided to prevent this flooding beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) schedules repetitive task. It will never (naturally) finish, so it won't become done. From method's documentation:

> the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the
>   executor

Thus, only if you call `future.cancel()` or `executor.terminate()` will the task become *done* and `future.isDone()` will then return `true`.

While one could potentially expect that `future` becomes *done* as soon as first task's execution completes, this is not the case for the following reasons:

1. once future becomes done it cannot be "undone" ("done" is a terminal state for a future), so `isDone` cannot report current execution state of a repetitive job
2. once future becomes done it makes no sense to cancel it (there isn't anything to cancel) -- that would not fit a repetitive task, which won't run indefinitely until canceled.

Comment: This is true. But the main reason is, as I mentioned a few seconds ago, that each finished task would return a new Future-Object. This would generate an endless series of Future-Objects. Therefore you can only hand in Runnables and no Callables as parameter when scheduling at a rate. Because Runnables don't return a Future-Object whereas Callables do.

Comment: There is no _value_ to be returned by the `Future` but the `Future` still can be done or not. Your comment nicely complements the explanation.

Comment: To everyone that answered... thank you it really helped me understand what is going on.